# Mongoimport dropping leading zeros from CSV file

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I have a CSV file that as a code in one of the fields.   It can have leading 0's in it which are important (key field).   When I do the import, if there is not an alpha character in that field it just puts 0 or 2 or 11 or whatever.

post import I can do something like this (but it takes forever):

```
db.p_table.find({ $where: 'this.key_code.length < 5' }).forEach(function(item) {
 base = '00000' + item.key_code; 
 item.key_code = base.slice(-5); 
 db.collection.save(item); 
});
```

Is there a way to tell the import command not do drop leading 0's for number looking key_code fields?

Comment: So you want `"key_code"` to be a string? https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoimport/#std-label-example-csv-import-types

Comment: Yes, I noticed some are integers and some are strings.   Is it possible at import to tell it to always be a string?    I found out the above doesn't work on the integer fields.

Comment: "Is it possible at import to tell it to always be a string?" ... Yes!  See the link in my first comment.

Comment: i missed the **--columnsHaveTypes** which is I think what I am looking for.   key_code was just an example, there are roughly 15 tables and a few fields per table that I need for relationships which having it switch between string and ints makes it most difficult.   Thank you for that.

Comment: Not sure I tried the has types and fields and headerline and it says they are incompatible.   I really don't want a record created for the header line.  I don't see a skip option to tell it to start on the second line of the csv file.

Comment: Using: `sed -i 1,1d file.csv` in my script to remove the header line